# Not able to package Play framework with java project into war

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework

Hi I am actually trying to deploy my application on AWS EC2 instance. For that I have my tomcat server running there. And I want to create a war file out of this play project. And there is no error that is shown in eclipse. My project directory is play-userReg :

```
C:\playdemo>play war play-userReg -o myapp.war
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.3.x-1.3.0RC1, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Warning: no application.mode defined in you conf/application.conf. Using DEV mode.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
14:25:36,029 INFO  ~ Starting C:\playdemo\play-userReg
14:25:36,431 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
14:25:37,969 ERROR ~

@6keg3pk9m
Cannot start in PROD mode with errors

Compilation error (In /app/Global.java around line 8)
The file /app/Global.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : GlobalSettings cannot be resolved to a type

play.exceptions.CompilationException: GlobalSettings cannot be resolved to a type
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:523)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:292)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:427)
        at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:604)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:308)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
~ Please fix compilation errors before packaging WAR
~
```

My build.sbt file is :

```
name := """play-userReg"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.0" % "provided",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "3.2.2.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.2.RELEASE",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.11.0",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-mongodb" % "1.2.0.RELEASE",
    "cglib" % "cglib" % "2.2.2",
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

Comment: The error clearly says there is an Issues with `Compilation error (In /app/Global.java around line 8)`.

Comment: Hi @Jatin that for the reply. But as I can see there is no error in my eclipse.

Comment: Well, maybe you should tell sbt that everything is fine in eclipse then  :) The compiler is the source of truth, don't rely on a buggy IDE to know if there is an error in your code.

Comment: How come that you have a `build.sbt` but a framework in version `1.3`?

Comment: I created my project with activator 1.2.10

Comment: when I say activator run  my application runs fine. But if I am trying to package it into a war, then I am getting this error.

Comment: Play 2 doesn't support `war` packaging anymore. Use this plugin: https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to build a Play 2 project with Play 1.

You should run "activator" instead of "play".

Comment: when I say activator run my application runs fine. But if I am trying to package it into a war, then I am getting this error

Comment: But then still you should do it by using "activator war" instead of "play war", because "play" refers to Play1 and "activator" refers to Play2.